# Get all the dates in a week of the selected date in jquery date picker?

Tags: jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I am creating a task list with number of hours worked to be entered against each task along each day of the week. So if a user clicks on a particular week dates then I need to get all the days' dates into hidden fields. Then I will use them to identify the which hours entry is against which date and insert them into the database. So for this how can I use jquery date picker plugin to get these dates in a week. Please suggest a way as I have been searching for this for long. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fetch a `Date` from your datepicker, you could use `getDay` to fetch the current week day (0 being Sunday), and calculate the offsets from there.

[Sample Code](http://pastebay.com/76256)

Comment: Sorry. I want to pick the dates of 7 days in the selected week.

Comment: yes. but I take it you use the regular datepicker, where the user actually clicks a date...? then based on that, you can check whether what day in the week, whichever week it is, and calculate the rest of the dates from there. if `selectedDate.getDay()` is 3, the user has picked a Wednesday, and you can calculate the Monday using `selectedDate.setDate(-2)` etc

Comment: Thanks for that ... i am trying it out .. in the mean time can you paste any sample code available. Thanks again for ur help..

Comment: Thank you veryt much. This is why I love to say i am a SO member. Thanks again..That helped me a lot. I will keep in touch with you.

Comment: -1 Because using pastebay which redirects to some advertised site instead of your sample code which basically puts advertisement into your answer